# combine two datetime to one and use it in linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a linq query, need combine datetimeA.date+DateitmB.time. How to do that?

```
var sample = (from e in dataContext.tblA.Include("tblB")
              where (e.Active == true && DateTime.Parse(e.DateA.ToShortDateString() + " " +e.DateB.ToShortTimeString()) >= DateTime.Now )
                        select new 
                        {
                        ...
                        }).ToList();
```

I tried using

```
new DateTime(e.DateA.Year, e.DateA.Month,e.DateA.Day,e.DateB.Hour,e.DateB.Minute,e.DateB.Second) >= DateTime.Now
```

but I can't do that in linq

Comment: How would you combine the dates? like if you did  9/19/2013 + 9/19/2013 what would you be expecting. Nevermind i see ones a time sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Entity Framework Date and Time Canonical Functions to achieve this - as listed here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx

For your specific example - something like this might work.

```
var sample =
    (
        from e in dataContext.tblA.Include("tblB")
        where e.Active == true && System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(e.DateA.Year, e.DateA.Month,e.DateA.Day,e.DateB.Hour,e.DateB.Minute,e.DateB.Second) >= DateTime.Now
        select new 
        {
            ...
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your query is not getting translated to the under laying data source (may be SQL). That is why you are getting error.

You are combining `Date` from one object and `Time` from one object and then comparing it with `DateTime.Now` you can try the following:

```
var sample = (from e in dataContext.tblA.Include("tblB")
              where e.Active == true 
                    && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(e.DateA) >= DateTime.Today //Compare date part only
                    && EntityFunctions.CreateTime(e.DateB.Hour, e.DateB.Minutes, e.DateB.Seconds) >= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay //Time part only
                        select new 
                        {
                        ...
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: This could potentially give incorrect results if `DateA` also has time attached to it.

Comment: @Khan, from the OP code, it appears that the comparison is done with Current Date to `DateA`'s Date Part and Current Time to `DateB`'s Time part. I am not sure what do you mean by Time attached to `DateA`, The OP is clearly trying to ignore it

Comment: Ah yes, I looked past the `ToShortDateString()`.  But to another point, EF doesn't support `.Date` nor `.TimeOfDay`.

Comment: @Khan, I didn't know about that. I guess in that case [these functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(v=vs.100).aspx)  would be helpful. Just modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime.Date + DateTime.TimeOfDay` to combine both

```
// ...
  .Select(data => new{ combined = data.DateA.Date + data.DateB.TimeOfDay, data })
  .Where(x => x.data.Active && x.combined >= DateTime.Now)
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. Maybe do it before your linq and if it works then add it in or just set it to a variable if not

```
DateA.Add(DateB.time)
```